# Can't install RuneScape (tried Ubuntu client and Wine)

Tags: wine, gnome-terminal, runescape

I was trying to get back into the game RuneScape the other day, and tried copying and pasting the terminal code on RuneScape's website for the Ubuntu client:

```
sudo -s -- << EOF
wget -O - https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu/runescape.gpg.key | apt-key add -
mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu trusty non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/runescape.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y runescape-launcher
EOF
```

Each time I tried this it would say it could not find "package runescape-launcher." I even tried entering the lines one by one, starting with the second line, rather than copying and pasting the whole block. Does this have to do with my 32-bit system?

I decided to maybe try Wine instead with the Windows .exe install file (not ideal, but if it works and lags, at least it works). I got Wine running the installer and it said it would download 2015 C++ Windows redistributable. I clicked all the default file locations.

Well it tried to install and popped up that it could not install the C++ 2015 redistributable. I tried downloading it myself but it was a Windows file so I wasn't sure where to put it. Does Wine have some special directory or something? Also, it was attempting to download one other thing, I forget what it was but can check if you need to know, and it was unsuccessful in downloading that too.

Any help with installing either of these programs (Ubuntu client or Windows .exe through Wine) would be greatly appreciated. I tried installing the older version of RuneScape, which came as a .msi, and it worked fine in Wine without the "could not install C++" thing. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with a 32-bit system. Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just go to `runescape.com` in a web browser?  The Runescape Client is riddled with bugs.  I also think it uses an IE layer, which will cause issues in the long run via Wine.

Comment: I would love to have it work in the browser, but it says Browser not supported even though I'm using Mozilla on Ubuntu 16.04. Any ideas? Maybe I can give it another try masking my browser. I'll try these solutions tomorrow and let you guys know what works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

The unofficial Linux client is a bundle of perl scripts that replicate the Windows client behaviour like reading the parameters to use from a .prm text file and also, it makes sure that OpenGL works when using Java7/OpenJDK7 which, according to its developer, is an issue for Linux users due to Java being unable to find its own libraries without wrapping it inside the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Without this, Linux users would have safemode available as the display mode, which gives about 4fps.

The package also includes a RuneScape Client Settings GUI which lets the users change some script and client settings, as well as a jagexcache cleaner.

Install the unofficial RuneScape Linux Client

runescape

To install the unofficial RuneScape Linux/Unix Game Client in Ubuntu 12.10, 12.04, 11.10, 11.04, 10.10 or 10.04, use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hikariknight/unix-runescape-client
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unix-runescape-client
```

Note: the "unix-runescape-client" package is a dummy package which will install OpenJDK if it is not installed so if you want to use a custom Java package (Sun/Oracle Java) without installing OpenJDK you can just install the "runescape" package instead.

There is also a video on how install the RuneScape client in Ubuntu, [HERE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NooByJuuULs).

After the installation completes, run RuneScape from the menu / Dash. The first time you run the RuneScape launcher, a terminal window will be displayed which lets you select the official (.jar) client you want to use and once the download finishes, you can launch RuneScape.

The unofficial RuneScape Linux/Unix Game Client developer mentions that the game runs dramastically faster in 32bit Java than on 64bit Java on Linux because the client jvm (hotspot client) is not available for 64bit.

There are some known issues when running RuneScape on Linux, but there are also some fixes available - check them out on the RuneScape wiki.